# ClassNotFoundexception in php-java bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I am new to php/java bridge

```
<?php

require_once("localhost:8087/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
$world = new java("Test");
    echo $world->query("sample");
?>
```

this is my php file for calling a desktop application's Test class, but it is showing an ClassNotfoundException.

Comment: Could you add the exception as well? It will help determine if it's the test class itself it can't find or something else.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your Java class is inside a package.
If the class is inside a package (eg. com.stackoverflow) you need to instanziate your class with the package name:

```
$world = new java("com.stackoverflow.Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the exception it looks like you lack the test class in your jvm classpath. You say you want to run a desktop application, so I would suggest you go through this [guide](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/desktop-apps.php) (Again? :), to see if you missed something in the setup.

Also you could remove the `enter code here` block.